# Rotation performed correctly only when Model-View-Projection multiplication is performed on the shader

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I'm using GLM with OpenGL 3.3. I have my code setup to draw a shape and I am using GLM to create the Projection, View and Model matrices like so:

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
);

glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);

glm::mat4 model; // during main loop
model = glm::rotate(model, time*glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

And then sending them to the shader with:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(proj * view * model));
```

And in the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But the shape is not displayed correcly, it is not rotating around its center like it should, instead it is translated a bit from its center and it's rotating around the middle of the screen.

Though if I send the 3 matrices to the shader as uniforms and perform the calculation for the position there:

```
gl_Position = model * view * projection * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
```

It work as expected. I tried all possible combinations for *proj x view x model* (even though that is the correct order), tried assigning the multiplication to a *final* matrix and then passing it to the shader, etc.

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried turning the `transpose` parameter off? If I recall correctly, both OpenGL and GLM use column-major matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much @NicoSchertler, thas was actually it! I did not mean to use it, I must have done it by mistake and overlooked it when reviewing the code. If you want, you can send an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!